# frame drops in Nvidia jetson Tk1 with IDS camera at 50 fps

Tags: camera, computer-vision, nvidia, odroid

I am using Tk1 with IDS camera (Model Number: UI5241LE-M) with CAT 6 ethernet cable to capture frames at 50 fps with 1280x1024.  And it is giving a lot of frame drops.  I am not exactly getting why it is not able to capture frames at 50 fps ? Any idea about it ? I was expecting that tk1 will work without any issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you displaying the image while capturing?  Can you capture with the same setup at 50fps using a PC?

Comment: yes, I am using ueyecamera manager which display the image as well

Comment: Can you get 50fps without displaying the image?